# Keypress event happening twice

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am monitoring an editable table I have on one of my website for the keypress of the enter key. I can get the keypress and I can get the information I need from the table, but what worries me is that the `keypress` event is happening twice. Here is the code and I will explain my `console.log`s.

```
    element.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var key = e.keyCode;
        if (key === 13) {
            console.log("Just some Ajax");
        }
    });
```

The string "Just some Ajax" is getting logged twice. And when you log out `e.type` the event `keypress` is logged twice. 
Why is this event being triggered twice from one keypress (I have no other eventlisteners listening for a keypress) and what can I do to prevent that?

---

### Edit to show full code being interacted with

I am serving a table from a sql database with some information in it. Here is the PHP that 'turns into the HTML':

```
$WOT .="<tr id='$WOInfo[0]'>";
$WOT .="<td id='n$WOInfo[0]' onclick='edit(this, b$WOInfo[0])' contenteditable='false'>$WOInfo[1]</td>";
$WOT .="<td id='u$WOInfo[0]' onclick='edit(this, b$WOInfo[0])' contenteditable='false'>$WOInfo[2]</td>";
$WOT .="<td id='p$WOInfo[0]' onclick='edit(this, b$WOInfo[0])' contenteditable='false'>$WOInfo[3]</td>";
$WOT .="<td id='d$WOInfo[0]' onclick='edit(this, b$WOInfo[0])' contenteditable='false'>$WOInfo[4]</td>";
$WOT .="<td>";
$WOT .= "<button 
               type='button' 
               title='Delete'
               onclick='confDel($WOInfo[0])'>Delete</button>";
$WOT .= "<button type='button' title='Update' id='b$WOInfo[0]' onclick='confEdit($WOInfo[0], n$WOInfo[0], u$WOInfo[0], p$WOInfo[0], d$WOInfo[0])' disabled>Update</button></td>";
$WOT .="</tr>";
```

Here is the full JavaScript function from the original example:

```
function edit(element, ID){
    'use strict';
    element.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    element.style.color = "black";
    element.setAttribute("contentEditable", "true");
    ID.disabled = false;
        element.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var key = e.keyCode;
            if (key === 13) {
                console.log("Just some Ajax");
                var update = element.innerText; 
            }
        });
}
```

And here is the rest of the JavaScript code the HTML is interacting with (and please, don't judge too hard on how the variables are being sent, I'm refactoring it all to use AJAX haha):

```
function confEdit(ID, name, username, password, description){
  var name = (name.innerText);
  var username = (username.innerText);
  var password = (password.innerText);
  var description = (description.innerText);
  var action;
  var r = confirm ("Are you sure you want to update the entry? This cannot be undone.");
    if (r === true){
      action = window.location = "/radiosite/other/index.php?action=upWOEntry&&ID="+ID+"&&name="+name+"&&username="+username+"&&password="+password+"&&description="+description+"";
    } else {
      action = window.location = "/radiosite/other/index.php?action=wopass";
    }
    return action;
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are not adding it to the element twice?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I'm not sure of that 100%, but I can't see where I would be adding it to the element twice, because I'm only using that variable in one function in the JS

Comment: If you inspect the element in chrome, and select the `Event Listeners` tab (instead of the `Styles` tab) you will see a list of event listeners on that element.

Comment: I would guess maybe the event is bubbling.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I inspected the element and there is only one event listener there, a 'click' element. I have a click event doing something else in my JS, but I don't think it is that event interfering because when I logout `e.type` I get `keypress` twice. I also thought it was weird that my keypress event was not there when I inspected the element.

Comment: @AndrewLi that's what I originally thought, but I set the attribute to false and it didn't fix the issue

Comment: Have you tried `e.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: @AndrewLi Yup, I get the same result.

Comment: Can we see your HTML?

Comment: Can you provide a complete, self-contained example? (Also known as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).) What causes the `.addEventListener()` code shown to be run, is that inside some other function, or...?

Comment: @AndrewLi added code above.

Comment: @nnnnnn added above

Comment: @AdamMcGurk You do realize that every time you click you add another event listener so you're just piling on the event listeners?

Comment: @AndrewLi right, I understand I have a ton of event listeners, but I need that many because I want every `td` to be editable. But I don't see how the click events would be interfering with my original question, because the double events are both logged as keypress events

Comment: @AdamMcGurk That doesn't matter. The fact is every time you click, you add another event listener, then another, then another. So if you click a td twice, then when you type, it'll run the event handler twice.

Comment: @AndrewLi I'm not sure I follow, because I just went to the site and I clicked into two different `td`s but I only pressed enter in one of them and the event still logged twice. And if I understand you correctly, the event should have logged four times because I clicked into two different `td`s and pressed enter in one of them.

Comment: @AdamMcGurk Well, the event handler would only execute *for that td* which would be 2.

Comment: @AndrewLi Oh, I see what you mean now! So is there a way to fix the event redundancy with how my code is setup right now? Because I tried selecting all `td`s that were children of the table, but when I tried to append them to an event listener, the console logged out that I couldn't do it like that because it was the incorrect type to append to event listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while of head scratching, I was talking to a networking buddy (not even a programmer) about this issue, just to have someone to talk to and just said: "well why do you need the events to be nested??" And I realized he was right. And I realized I could just put an event listener on all of my `td`'s, so I really had to rewrite a lot of the code, but it was all for the best. Here was the `HTML/PHP` that was needed (abbreviated for length's sake. The only thing pertinent that I left out was a hidden input field in the bottom of the table):

```
<tr id='o$OTHERInfo[0]'>";
<td id='name'>$OTHERInfo[1]</td>
<td id='username'>$OTHERInfo[2]</td>
<td id='password'>$OTHERInfo[3]</td>
<td id='description'>$OTHERInfo[4]</td>
```

And here was the JavaScript:

```
var table = document.getElementById("passwordTable");
var data = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var index = data[i];
    index.addEventListener("click", function (index){ 
        td = index.path[0];
        td.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        td.style.color = "black";
        td.setAttribute("contentEditable", "true");}, false);
                index.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
                var key = e.keyCode;
                    if (key === 13) {
                        // just some ajax                       }
            }, false)
```